# Using a reusable directive for form inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just read through the [directive docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and I'm still not understanding how I'd accomplish the following with reusable code. I have multiple form fields that would best be used in a `select > option` setup, however I'm looking to replace that with a directive with a template because of how mobile browsers handle `select`s (iOS magnifies the `option`s and some of my values are too long to be viewed in the display).

So my template would look something like this:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="option" ng-repeat="option in form.questionOneOptions" ng-click="selectOption(option)">
        {{option}}
        <i class="checkIcon" ng-if="option.isSelected"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be the only thing on the detail page. Its parent page being the list of fields you're filling out, which is where the data needs to be available. I just don't know where to start on the directive. There is an isolated scope for each question, which holds the options for that question. There needs to be a way to give the directive the list of options. There is an encompassing scope for all the questions to keep the recorded answers in a single object like `form`.

I know I could do this with a single controller and copy/pasting the above and changing `form.questionOneOptions` with one massive object living in the controller, but I'm trying to do this the *right* way by limiting my DOM manipulation to directives.

Comment: it would be helpful if you included some of the code you've written so far to try and make the magic happen

Comment: So far I'm just using `select` and `option`s. Each select is paired with an `ng-model`. I just don't know where to start with this directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the html you have there as the template for your directive. Then you implement selectOptions in your link function.

```
app.directive('gsQuestion', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            options: '='
        },

        template:'<div class="list">'+
                   '<div class="option" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="selectOption(option)">'+
                    '{{option}}'+
                    '<i class="checkIcon" ng-if="option.isSelected"></i>'+
                 '</div></div>',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.selectOption = function(option)
            {
                // implement selectOption
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can use the directive in your html.

```
<gs-question ng-model="myValue1" options="form.questionOneOptions"></gs-question>
<gs-question ng-model="myValue2" options="form.questionTwoOptions"></gs-question>
```

Comment: Cool, this was a good starting point for what I need. I also needed to add `ngModel` to the link params and use `ngModel.$setViewValue(option)` in order to update the model for my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, a directive can share data to/from the view through the use of the directive's `$scope` variables.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('mySampleDirective', function(){
  return{
   restrict: 'AE',
   scope: {
    data: '=' // this sets up a two way binding 
   }
}, 
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
   console.log(scope.data) // <---- this is where you would do DOM manipulation, 
                           // because you have access to the element.
 }
})
```

And then in your markup, pass in the data you want to make available in your directive.

```
<my-sample-directive data="FeeFee"></my-sample-directive>
```